# Multiple sites on the same host; sessions?

Tags: php, session, hosting

I run two sites on the same webhost (why not take advantage of unlim. bandwidth and relatively large storage?). The problem I am having is that sessions from one site are leaking onto the other.

`$_SESSION["username"] = $somevar;`

On Site A, if I `echo` that session variable, it will give the correct output as expected, but on Site B it does the same thing.

How do I make sessions distinct from another without altering a lot of my code? I know `session_name()` exists, but this requires me to change all of my `$_SESSION` initializations to correspond to the given session name. Surely there's an alternative that does not require this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the session save path for your applications to a different location.

In your ini

```
session.save_path /secure/session/path
```

Or in the application itself

```
session_save_path('/secure/session/path');
```

(Don't set the path to anything inside the site's document root)